# Shared Table not printing on Client

Tags: lua, server, client, lua-table, garrys-mod

Basically I have a `SHARED` lua file where I define the table.
I did this because I thought if we define the Table in a shared file we can use it client and server side.

SHARED.lua:

```
TableA = {}
```

Then I edit it on a `SERVER` lua file.

SERVER.lua:

```
function UpdateTable()
    // Clean Table first
    for k in pairs(TableA) do
        TableA[k] = nil
    end
    ... not worth showing the rest ...
    // Insert New Values
    for i=1, 10 do
        table.insert(TableA, result[i])
    end
    // Debug Print
    print(table.ToString(TableA)) // It Prints every value correctly
end
```

Now when I try to print it client side, it says the Table exists but it's empty.

CLIENT.lua:

```
print(table.ToString(TableA))// Prints "{}" and it shouldn't be empty
```

Note: UpdateTable() runs every 5min

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently when we define a table shared, doesn't mean the values will be shared through the server and client. It only means that the code will run on both server/client.
You have to network them for them to "share" the values on the table.

Comment: Yep, you're exactly right. The `net` library is the best way to achieve server/client sync, in fact you can send entire tables through the net library using `net.WriteTable` though I would only recommend this for initial state and then sending incremental updates using the various net functions.